# What does this new icon mean that Conquest of the Wizardlands added?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor, dod-conquest-wizardlands

So the new expansion to Dungeons of Dredmor added a new "Encrusting" system.  This system has added at least one new stat, or mechanic, or pulley/lever/other spinning thing to the game.  Problem is, there's no help in the game, and this new icon does not show up on the character screen, so I don't know what it is!

For your viewing pleasure, here is an example, complete with freehand circle![image: Strange icon].

Does anyone know what this icon mean?  If it's a new game mechanic, what is this new mechanic, and how does it work?

Comment: Much love for the freehand circle! Also, I can't wait to get my clockwork chainaxe so I can encrust it with the enhanced Rearden coating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That number indicates the percentage chance for the item to gain instability when the encrust is applied. For the Steam Drive, this means when it is applied to a weapon, there is a 6% chance for the instability level to increase. The instability level indicates the chance to cause a miscast effect on yourself when you are hit (for armour) or when you hit something (for weapons). The instability chance is negative on accessory encrusts. I'm not sure why this is, possibly just to ensure that instability will never increase on accessories.

The miscast chance adds additively in the case of different encrusts, and multiplicatively when using multiple of the same encrust.

Example:

Steam Drive (6%) + Steam Drive (6%) = 6% * 6% = 36% (Yes, I realize this isn't how multiplication works. Shhh.)

Steam Drive (6%) + Ruinous Sheathing (6%) = 6% + 6% = 12%

Instability chance does not have a cap, but anything over 100% is irrelevant.

Comment: So if I add Steam Drive twice, that weapon has a 12% chance to miscast?  But if I added a different encrust, the weapon has a (X * 6)% chance to miscast?  How does miscast work on non-weapons?  Check every turn or something?  Also, is it possible to encrust past 100%?  If so, does anything bad happen?

Comment: Added other information to my answer.

Comment: Those calculations could, however, be wrong. Hopefully I can clarify them once I get a chance to test it myself.

Comment: I'll poke around when I get a chance to test myself.  If adding more effects reduces the chance to miscast, then that sounds like something is off.

Comment: It doesn't reduce the chance to miscast, it just doesn't increase it quite as much as having multiple of the same encrust. I really wish I could test it, but I can't make anything right now, as my materials are all in the pocket dimension, and my inventory vanishes if I enter it.

Comment: Okay, I was entirely wrong here. I misunderstood an explanation. Fixing it now.

Comment: Wait...part of your answer doesn't make sense now.  "The miscast chance adds multiplicatively in the case of different encrusts, and additively when using multiple of the same encrust." does not match your examples; it's the opposite.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, you must be going insane >.>